# Why aren't there any profile stats on Jobs?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

In Careers, there was a module on the home page showing some statistics about my profile, as public views, employer views, search hits, and so on. I couldn't find those data in Jobs. Were they removed? If so, was there a specific reason for that?

Comment: Hello Gustavo, some folks working on the Jobs integration project will give you an answer soon :)

Answer (score 15):

We didn't include it because we've received mixed feedback about it, and are unsure whether or not it's useful.  I am interested in your feedback though, to better understand how you found it useful.

Comment: A moderator with 1 rep? Can I ask how?

Comment: @Druzion Des is a Stack Overflow employee. (Check their profile.) Employees get diamonds on sites they need them on.

Comment: @Kendra Oh, an employees only ever have 1 rep?

Comment: She is a PM, not a programmer, so she doesn't have any SO rep :)

Comment: I believe it is a very interesting tool when one designs its own CV. I could know if adding this or that increased my profile views, or I could know if my CV is "hot" enough to attract employers (or at leas employer views).

Comment: What was the "mixed feedback"? I wonder how having more info can be bad. No one is forcing you to look at the numbers, after all.

Comment: As @AnderBiguri commented above, I've used it to get feedback when optimizing my CV.

Comment: I miss these counters too, they gave me some insights on how good my changes were doing. Maybe asking users on meta for feedback or ideas is the way to go.

Comment: The profile stats were really useful for me as well.